# laravel sum and crosstab

Tags: mysql, crosstab

hi i am trying to solve this problem from 2 days please help. I have a table like below. i am trying to get crosstab display

**expenditures**

```
id  name
1   exp1
2   exp2
3   exp3
4   exp4
5   exp5
```

**stations**

```
id  name
 1  station1
 2  station2
 3  station3
 4  station4
```

**expenses**

```
expenditure_id  station_id  year  month expense
1               1           2015    1   10
1               2           2015    1   20
1               3           2015    1   15
1               4           2015    1   10
1               1           2015    2   20
1               1           2015    3   30
1               1           2015    4   40      
2               1           2015    1   20      
2               1           2015    2   10
2               1           2015    3   20
```

I am trying get result like this

for **year 2015**

```
expenditure station1  station2  station3  station4
exp1        100        20       15        0
exp2        50         0        0         0
```

---

where value of station1 station2 will be the sum of month expense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the mysql query as your requirement, use Laravel query builder to run this query as raw query, if you donot know how to run raw query in laravel let me know, in the mean while run the query in phpmyadmin/mysql client and see whether its give you the desired output .

```
    SELECT y.expenditure,
      MAX(CASE y.station WHEN 'station1'  THEN y.totalexpense END) 'station1',
      MAX(CASE y.station WHEN 'station2'  THEN y.totalexpense END) 'station2',
      MAX(CASE y.station WHEN 'station3'  THEN y.totalexpense END) 'station3',
      MAX(CASE y.station WHEN 'station4'  THEN y.totalexpense END) 'station4'
   FROM (
        SELECT exp.name AS expenditure,st.name AS station,x.totalexpense
        FROM expenditures AS exp
        LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT expenditure_id,station_id,SUM(expense) as totalexpense
        FROM expenses
        WHERE year = '2015'
        GROUP by expenditure_id,station_id
        )
        AS x ON exp.id = x.expenditure_id
        LEFT JOIN stations AS st  ON x.station_id = st.id
    ) AS y
    GROUP BY y.expenditure
```

I assume you have only 4 stations, if stations are unknown numbers then you can use a prepared statement and create this dynamically:

Comment: Thanks , yes stations is unknown number could you please show how to use prepared statement

Comment: yes but it will not show the result of station whose id is not in expenses table

Comment: I updated the code above, I replaced the inner join with left join, try now and see

Comment: no it is still not showing the stations that is not in expenses table

Comment: i used SELECT exp.name AS expenditure,st.name AS station,x.totalexpense
        FROM expenditures AS exp
        LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT expenditure_id,station_id,SUM(expense) as totalexpense
        FROM expenses
        WHERE year = '2015'
        GROUP by expenditure_id,station_id
        )
        AS x ON exp.id = x.expenditure_id
        LEFT JOIN stations AS st  ON x.station_id = st.id        but it only giving the result of station that is in expense table any idea

Comment: yes sure, it will give only if you have related model, if so what I will recommend is , query the station which which is not in the expanse table and make a union to the previous result, please try something and post, here so i will help you

Comment: could you please give some more hint

Comment: tried this 
SELECT exp.name AS expenditure,st.name AS station,x.totalexpense
FROM stations AS st
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT expenditure_head_id,station_id,SUM(expense) as totalexpense
FROM expense_details
WHERE year = '2015'
GROUP by expenditure_head_id,station_id
)
AS x ON st.id = x.station_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN expenditure_heads AS exp  ON x.expenditure_head_id = exp.id   it will give station null if not in expense_details how to make crosstab